# coin rotation, as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, physics

What's the better way to make a coin rotation? I tried Math.random, but the coin doesn't wobble correctly.

**starter code**

```
//ROTATION
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
function enterFrameHandler(event:Event):void
{
/*
ADD VELOCITY, GRAVITY, ACCELERATION
*/
coin.rotationY += 8;
}
```

**tried this, but it has no gravity or accelleration**

```
//ROTATION AND RANDOM MATH
function wobble():void {
var wobble = ((Math.random()*4)-2);
flk.rotationY -= 11+wobble/2;
flk.rotationX -= 2+wobble/20;
}
var myInterval:uint = setInterval (wobble, 40);
```

[alt text http://www.ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/coin.jpg](http://www.ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/coin.jpg)

Comment: if you specify what you're going to use this for it'll be easier to help. is it going to be a simple animation? does it need to be random?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual maths involved in a spinning coin (or Euler's Disk) is [fairly complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_disk), and definitely not random. There's more detail [here](http://www.real-world-physics-problems.com/eulers-disk.html) if you're interested.

Comment: If anyone knows a simple equation let me know. Appreciate it.